# Can I fulfill my chiyuv to daven outside of the Shemone Esrei text?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

If I choose to talk to HaShem in English, and didn’t recite Shemone Esrei, would that fulfill my obligation to daven (for that zman of tefillah)?

Answer (score 4):

Talking with HaShem is always great but does not fulfill the (rabbinically mandated) shemoneh esrei prayer.

Keep in mind that one may be able to recite shemoneh esrei in any language one understands and fulfill ones obligation—see [here](https://shulchanarukh.alhatorah.org/Full/Orach_Chayyim/101/4#e0n6)

In any event there are occasions when one may pray a significantly shorter and more condensed version of shemoneh esrei and fully fulfill ones obligation—see [here](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/26149)

(See [here](https://rambam.alhatorah.org/Full/Tefillah_uBirkat_Kohanim/1.1#e0n6) where Rambam—contra Ramban [in ShM]—would presumably okay it from a biblical standpoint as it relates to the once daily obligation to pray—however not the shemoneh esrei obligation which is of rabbinic provenance).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150722/discussion-on-answer-by-nahum-can-i-fulfill-my-chiyuv-to-daven-outside-of-the-sh); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.